# Algorithm for Learning development

Tags: algorithm

This is a generic question - i know a bit of perl and python and i am looking in to learn programming so that once i get a hang of it i can start developing apps and then websites.
I request you to give me algorithm(steps :)) that what should be my approach towards learning it.
I have posted small questions on perl/python and i have recieved great help from everyone.
Note:- i am not in a hurry to learn i know it takes time and thats fine.

Please give any suggestions you think are valid(Please dun push me to learn Lisp,Haskell - i am a beginner)

Comment: You would probably be better asking this here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start with a good book that covers control structures, etc. (two I would recommend include [Head First Programming](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfprog/), or [learning to program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976694042) (which is a Ruby book).

After that, try out some basic stuff to learn your syntax, control structures, logic, etc. - some good sites for this are:

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)

[Coding Dojo](http://www.codingdojo.org/)

[Code Kata (pragpub)](http://codekata.pragprog.com/)

Then, move up from there (at that point you may want more framework specific stuff - MVC, Rails, etc.).

On a side note - language is largely irrelevant.  I'm mentoring an apprentice developer at work now (in C# but he's also looking at some Python), and in our last coding session, we wrote very little code, but spent a ton of time chewing through edge cases in a code kata.

(An addendum)

Once you're past basic control structures and syntax, you're going to find the toughest parts are design, abstraction, problem solving, etc. - so for those some good ways to pick up those skills include:

- Getting a good mentor (even a virtual one).
- Looking at LOTS of code.  If you are not in a dev shop, look at an opensource project you're interested in to see how other people code.
- Contribute to OSS
- Start small, and build something for yourself (I'm always partial to building your own blog site - like a Jedi has to build their own lightsaber ;)
- Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Bob - lucky me i just bought Head First Programming yesterday and was reading it while on the bus - thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Glad to help :)  I have a new developer who's doing this now so this is all pretty current for me.  If you need any tips, advice, etc. down the road, ping me offline - Always happy to help out a new developer.

Comment: Thanks Bob for the help offered - will definitely check with you in case of doubts.

Answer (score 2):

```
Step 1. Read
Step 2. Implement
Step 3. Repeat Step 1 until ur frustrated.
```

Simple Algo

Comment: Thanks Sushil  :) can you elaborate a bit more on each steps please .. :)

Comment: When i say read. Read everything about programming let it be whatever. it should make u feel interested enlightened and good. When i say implement, implement whatever u have learned coz without implementing you will forget it. And yes dont do any of the two things when u r frustrated or are feeling low. More u read more u start knowing there is no shortcut. Programming is a 10 yrs course or rather lifetime course. Read ur subjects talk to good people or find good mentors. If u dont find mentors select few of the programming heros and start following them. Like I follow JEFF ATWOOD.

Comment: thanks a lot Sushil iliked the lines - Programming is a 10 yrs course or rather lifetime course , And yes dont do any of the two things when u r frustrated or are feeling low. Thanks again